# Finding consecutive entries

Tags: c#, .net

I need to go through x number of objects.  Each object will have (int) ID and (bool) Complete fields.  The ID field will be unique.  How do I find objects that have Complete==true and consecutive ID fields.  For example, I want to find any 3 consecutive objects that meet this condition:

```
object (ID=1, Complete=true)
object (ID=2, Complete=true)
object (ID=3, Complete=false)
object (ID=4, Complete=true)
object (ID=5, Complete=true)
object (ID=6, Complete=true)
```

In the above, I should get objects 4, 5, 6.  Another example:

```
object (ID=1, Complete=true)
object (ID=2, Complete=true)
object (ID=3, Complete=false)
object (ID=4, Complete=true)
object (ID=5, Complete=true)
object (ID=6, Complete=false)
```

In this case, 3 consecutive objects of Complete==true do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var triplets = list.Select((item, index) => list.Skip(index).Take(3));
var candidates = triplets.Where(triplet => (triplet.Count() == 3) && 
                                           (triplet.All(item => item.Complete)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any built-in method in C# to do this, but it's a simple case of iterating over the object keeping a history of the previous two values. When prev_val_1 == prev_val_2 == curr_val, then print the result out with their corresponding IDs.

Comment: This is a good solution if you will ever need to look for a sequence of three values but it will get out of hand quickly if you try to extend for 4, 5, 6 etc. consecutive values.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 from obj in objects
     let next = obj.FirstOrDefault(t => t.id > obj.id && t.Completed)
     let nextNext = null == next ? null : objects.FirstOrDefault(t => t.id > next.id && t.Completed)
     where obj.completed && next != null && nextNext !=null select obj.id, next.id, nextNext.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = myList.Where((q, index) =>
    q.IsDone &&
    index < myList.Count-2 &&
    myList[index+1].IsDone &&
    myList[index+2].IsDone);
```